# How do I generate a "granule" index shapefile for ImageMosaic in GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, image-mosaic

I am experiencing a problem with generating a granule index shapefile for the [ImageMosaic plugin](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/image_mosaic_plugin/imagemosaic.html) in GeoServer; there are no clear instructions to follow.

Is there any way that I can generate it automatically using a raster dataset? I have a huge raster dataset to serve as WMS.

Comment: By the way, raster dataset is in geotiff format, Geoserver version is 2.1 (latest)

Answer (score 4):

[GDAL](http://www.gdal.org) is, as always, your friend. And [gdaltindex](http://www.gdal.org/gdaltindex.html) is the tool for the job.
You would run it from a command prompt like this:

```
gdaltindex -skip_different_projection mosaic_index.shp my_raster_directory/*.tif
```

Comment: thanks for the comment. When I run the command line it is giving error like this                                   "Warning 1: TIFFReadDirectory:Unknown field with tag 33918 (0x847e) encountered
Warning 1: TIFFFetchNormalTag:ASCII value for tag "GeoASCIIParams" does not end".

Comment: That appears to be an Intergraph-specific tag (see http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/docs/intergraph.html) that GDAL doesn't recognise. It shouldn't affect the output of the TIFF, and should be preserved verbatim. That it says "...does not end" may mean the source image is corrupt, but you can really only tell that by looking at the output.