# How to generate geoserver ImageMosaic properties not by geoserver?

Tags: geoserver

How can I generate properties for ImageMosaic not by geoserver? I can do index *.shp with gdal as [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18732/how-do-i-generate-a-granule-index-shapefile-for-imagemosaic-in-geoserver), but if geoserver not see .properties file it remove this index file and generate it again.